# Optimizing a strictly monotone function

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I am looking for algorithms to optimize a strictly monotonic function $f$ such that $f(x) < y$

$f : [a,b] \longrightarrow [c,d]
\qquad \text{where } [a,b] \subset {\mathbb N},  [c,d] \subset {\mathbb N}$
such that $\arg\max{_x} f(x) < y$

My first idea was to use a variant of binary search, pick a point $x$ in $[a,b]$ at random; if $f(x) > y$ then we eliminate $[x, b]$, and if $f(x) < y$ we eliminate $[a, x]$. We repeat this procedure until the solution is found.

Do you have any other ideas to maximize the function $f$ ?

Comment: Rather than picking at random, you could select the midpoint, test, elininate and repeat.

Comment: ... unless you know something more about $f$, then you could apply [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to $f(x)-y$.

Comment: Is $f$ defined on the natural numbers or on the whole interval $[a,b]$?  (I can't figure out the notation $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: If $f$ is strictly monotonic, then the maximum should be at $f(a)$ or $f(b)$...

Comment: @sdcvvc yes, but I want the maximum such that f(x) < y, y is a given value.

Comment: @Louis $f$ is defined on the discrete interval [a,b]. Sorry for the misleading notation.

Comment: @GhassenHamrouni: In that case, you are saying that you have a sorted array of numbers (the values of $f$), and you want to find the predecessor of $y$.  Just use binary search.

Comment: Are you aware of [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)? You'd have to modify to walk towards $f(x)=y$ and not $f'(x)=0$, but following the gradient depending on which side of $y$ you start on should work.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, this is an interesting approach too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the discrete intervals $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{N}$ and $[c,d]\subset\mathbb{N}$, we might be able to do slightly better than binary search using the midpoint without utilizing gradient descent.

Instead, we could use binary search with $x=a+\lfloor\frac{y-c}{d-c}(b-a)\rfloor$, which corresponds to the below intersection of the dotted purple line denoting $y$ and the line from $f(a)=c$ to $f(b)=d$.

[image: possible monotonic functions]

The red and blue lines represent the extremes of strictly monotonic functions.
When $f$ is linear, this would immediately find the closest $x$ (which is a big improvement over binary search with the midpoint). Without additional information, I think linearity is the best assumption you can make; there are as many concave functions as convex functions, as well as functions that switch.

One justification for not using gradient descent is if an array $[a,a+1,\dots,b]$ is simply mapped to another array of the same size but different range of data $[c,d]$, which is  randomly chosen (and sorted).

Otherwise, you could use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) as suggested by Dave Clarke or [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) as suggested by Raphael, [which I just learned are different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization).

Comment: Can you analyze the performance of this method on an arbitrary monotone function? How worse is it than binary search in the worst case?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, monotone functions can be quite arbitrary, so I don't know if I can analyze its average performance (other than assuming linearity), but at worst its the red line and $y=d-(b-a-1)$; I can't determine without further thought whether its still $O(\log n)$

Comment: When you do heuristic searches like this, you normally want to bound the interval to keep the $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ worst-case.